# gitignore: Ignore everything but specific file type in sub folder

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a .gitignore file which doesn't seem to work properly. It doesn't upload any files in the subdirectory as intended but I added an except all .cs files, but the subdirectory remains empty. Here is my code:

```
/*

!.gitignore

!my_repo/build/game/Assets/Scripts/*.cs
```

I want nothing apart from the .cs files and the .gitignore file. but the .cs files still doesn't seem to be picked up by git. Thanks.

PS.

I tried doing this also, but it doesn't work either:

```
!*.cs
```

Comment: According to the docs, gitignore processes subdirectories' rules as higher than the ones in parent directories. Try creating a `.gitignore` file inside `my_repo/build/game/Assets/Scripts` that contains the following: `!/*.cs`. Then, remove the `cs` exception line from your base `.gitignore` file.

Comment: is that the complete `.gitignore` file? check if you are ignoring a parent directory because if you are doing so that rule will be ignored unless you do what @AdilB says

Comment: I have tried this, and It doesn't work either...

Comment: Yes, that is the complete file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to include the directory too. See https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_examples

```
# Ignore all (assumes ignore is in my_repo/build/.gitignore)
/*
!.gitignore    

# Exempt directories
# Also ignore all files except the sub directories in the path
!game/
game/*
!game/Assets
game/Assets/*
!game/Assets/Scripts
game/Assets/Scripts/*

# Except your CS files
!game/Assets/Scripts/*.cs
```

-- Update to add clarity --

It seems counter-intuitive, but you have to *include* the directory explicitly first because:

> It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded. Git doesn’t list excluded directories for performance reasons, so any patterns on contained files have no effect, no matter where they are defined.

So you have to include the directory, then ignore everything in the directory by defualt, then create your exemption.

Comment: I have just tried this, and it's not working either.

Comment: Just want to make sure, but `my_repo` is actually in the path right? What's the repo structure in relation to this .gitignore file?

Comment: my repo is the name of my repo. the gitignore is in build

Comment: So you should update the path to `game/Assets/Scripts` in the example above

Comment: I'll update it to match what you said (as though the gitignore is in the build directory)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182958/discussion-between-wspurgin-and-zarrexx).

Comment: You'll need `!game` (or `!game/`) and `!game/Assets` (or again with slash appended) as well, and perhaps some ignore rules for files within those directories.

Comment: Works perfect :)

Comment: This solution is working for me after all others have failed.

Answer (score -2):

The line 
`!my_repo/build/game/Assets/Scripts/*.cs`
 contains the root folder while it shoouldn't and the
 `!*.cs`
 looks in only in root folder.

Should be like 
`/*
!.gitignore
!**/*.cs`

Then add with git add -f *

Comment: If you use `git add -f *` you're forcibly adding `*`... which adds everything regardless of whether it's in the gitignore or not.